# Referential integrity constraint

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

Is it possible that in composite primary key, for different values foreign keys refers to different tables.I am describing under.

Patient table has pat_id as PK.
Dependent table has pat_id,dep_Sno as PK (pat_id is FK from patient).
Patient_visit table has pat_id,dep_Sno,pat_visit as PK (pat_id,dep_Sno FK from dependent).

now the problem is that, when dep_Sno is 0 in patient_visit table, pointing to owner of patient_id, but info about owner of patient_id is already in patient table, and in dependent table, only the info of dependents will be saved so if a patient has dependents then their info will be in dependent table, that is why  dep_Sno>=1, if i put dep_Sno 0 in dependent table then it will be redundancy of data with patient table.

the info of owner of patient_id will be saved in both dependent table and Patient table, and i want to save info only in patient table, but when there is 0 in patient_visit table it fails the refrential integrity.

Comment: the info of owner of patient_id will be saved in both dependent table and Patient table, and i want to save info only in patient table, but when there is 0 in patient_visit table it fails the refrential integrity.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the dep_Sno from the Patient_visit table and just use pat_id and pat_visit as primary key for this table.

Comment: actually it is our project, and without dep_Sno, solution is not possible.

Comment: So you need to change your database design, because you can not ignore referential integrity rules.

Comment: there must be something by which we can handle this

Comment: additional constraints, or triggers, or something else